# Correct way to initialize a Keras sequential neural net?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am trying to initialize a Keras neural net.  My X is an matrix of shape (70000, 4) and I want 64 nodes in the first layer

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(X.shape)))
```

The above syntax is incorrect.  What is correct for my model.add()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 70000 samples with 4 points each.  In that case, use `Dense (64, input_shape=(4,))` and it should work.

The net would iterate over the samples in chunks of `batch_size`, although your net is likely small enough that you can set `batch_size` to a few thousand, or even the same size as the input.

**Old answer** I thought *each* sample was 70000x4...

The `Dense` layer cannot take a matrix as an input.  From the Keras documentation, `Dense(n_nodes, input_shape=(n_inputs,))` is equivalent to `Dense(n_nodes, input_dim=n_inputs)`, and that seems to be the only kind of input it takes.  Here `n_inputs` is an integer.

You basically have two options: either flatten X before passing it to the network with `X.reshape(-1)`, or use `Reshape` as the first layer, like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((X.size,), input_shape=(X.shape)))
model.add(Dense(64))
```

You may be able to use `Flatten` instead of `Reshape`, although I can't tell from the documentation if `Flatten` can take an `input_shape` parameter.